# How to get mysql data in javascript for dynamic form adding

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, forms, dynamic

I need help..
I create dynamically html form field adding using javascript..its work fine..but the problem is, I want to get the select box value from mysql database, how to do that..I'm stuck..

This is my code :

```
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
    var count = 1;          
    $('.addmore')['on']('click', function() {
    count += 1;
    html = '<tr>';
    html += '<td><input class="case" type="checkbox"/></td>';html += '<td>   
    <input id="rows_' + count + '" name="rows[]" value="'+ count +'" 
    type="hidden" required><input type="text" name="tgl ' + count + '" 
    id="tgl_' + count + '" class="form-control changesNo" autocomplete="off" 
    data-mask="99/99/9999" ondrop="return false;" onpaste="return false;" 
    required></td>';
    html += '<td><input type="text" data-type="productName" name="item ' + 
    count + '" id="itemName_' + count + '" class="form-control 
    autocomplete_txt" autocomplete="off" required></td>';
    html += '<td><select name="codefin ' + count + '" id="codefin_' + count 
    + '" class="form-control"><option value="">- CODE -</option><?php 
    $sel_kat="select * from catfinance where status='Publish'"; 
    $q=mysql_query($sel_kat); while($data_prov=mysql_fetch_array($q)){?>
   <option value="<?php echo $data_prov["codecatfinance"] ?>"><?php echo 
   $data_prov["codecatfinance"] ?></option><?php}?></select>';
    html += '<td><input type="number" name="debit ' + count + '" id="debit_' 
    + count + '" class="form-control changesNo" autocomplete="off" 
    onkeypress="return IsNumeric(event);" ondrop="return false;" 
    onpaste="return false;" required></td>';
    html += '<td><input 
    type="number" name="credit ' + count + '" id="credit_' + count + '" 
    class="form-control changesNo" autocomplete="off" onkeypress="return 
    IsNumeric(event);" ondrop="return false;" onpaste="return false;" 
    required></td>';html += '</tr>';
    $('table')['append'](html);
    i++;
    });
    });
    </script>
```

Thank you for your help.. I really appreciate :)

Comment: This is almost impossible to ready. You may want to think about some courtesy formatting. Indents would help...returns...stuff like that.

Comment: Another side note, the `mysql_*` set of functions is deprecated and removed as of PHP7. Look at `PDO` or `mysqli_*`

Comment: You have  the sql call for the options, so where ever you have the saved selected value stored, you would just do an `if` clause and do ` selected` on the option if they equal each other.

Comment: thank you all, how to fix the code?..Thank you

Comment: Do you have the user's answers stored?

Answer (score 1):

**Example:**

```
<?php 
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
        echo "<option value='".$row['path']."'>'".$row['name']."'</option>";
    }
 ?>

$row['path'] // will get the value of the select box value.
$row['name'] // will fetch the list(dropdown)
```

Comment: I already put php mysql in javascript, but its not work..can you help me to fix it?..thank you

Comment: @user3828720  


<select id="company" name="company">
<option <?php if ($company == 1 ) echo 'selected' ; ?> value="1">Apple</option>
<option <?php if ($company == 2 ) echo 'selected' ; ?> value="2">Samsung</option>
<option <?php if ($company == 3 ) echo 'selected' ; ?> value="3">HTC</option>
</select>

Comment: @user3828720 try to echo the value 'selected' if the value matches the the value from the database

Answer (score 0):

You need a server-side program to interact with the database.